# How to add extra data to wx.TreeCtrl items? wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

How can I add extra data to the appended tree items in the `wx.TreeCtrl` named `fileTree` below. I read data from a text file into an array to build the tree. The append items in the tree are the filenames of images but I would like to know how to add the full filepath to each item. The full filepath must show when I double on an item instead of just its filename.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):

    self.fileTree = wx.TreeCtrl(self, size=(200, 100))
    self.root = self.fileTree.AddRoot('Images')
    self.allImages = self.fileTree.AppendItem(self.root, 'All')
    imgLst=self.generateList(imagelist)# Reads a text file with filepaths into list

    for item in imgLst:
        tmp=item
        tmp = tmp[tmp.rfind("\\")+1:tmp.rfind(".")]
        self.fileTree.AppendItem(self.allImages, tmp)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.onTreeDClick, self.fileTree)

def onTreeDClick(self,event):
    print 'Double clicked on', self.fileTree.GetItemText(event.GetItem())

def generateList(self, fname):
    f = open(fname, "rb")

    a=[]
    for line in f:
        a.append(line.strip())
    return a
```

Comment: @Rostyslav Dzinko thanks for the edit, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within [`wx.TreeCtrl`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TreeCtrl-class.html) you can have items with some data associated with them. This data is a `wx.TreeItemData` class instance that can contain arbitrary Python object. Let's clarify that with a code:

```
# Let fullPath be holding full path you your file (i.e. in Python string)
fileInfo = wx.TreeItemData(fullPath)
```

This `fileInfo` instance of [`wx.TreeItemData`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TreeItemData-class.html) object can that be associated with arbitrary `wx.TreeCtrl` item:

```
# Let item variable contain your tree item object
self.fileTree.SetPyData(item, fileInfo)
```

Here, in the code above we've associated item object with `fileInfo` object. You can get access to the associated object in your event handler:

```
self.fileTree.GetPyData(event.GetItem())
```

That's all. Note, that any Python object can be associated with `wx.TreeCtrl` item.

Comment: thanks, how can i get the text of object when using self.fileTree.GetPyData(event.GetItem()),?

Comment: This worked->> currentImg=self.fileTree.GetPyData(event.GetItem())
print currentImg.GetData()